# properly executing single line in vs code python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

hello this is sth simple probably but I want to execute my python code line by line in vs code

I am executing the same code without  problem in jupiter notebook

I do it by pressing Shift + Enter after selecting line

Now a problem

I have a very simple code

```
import numpy
import juliacall
```

When I invoke run code (ctrl + alt + n) no problem with that all works
Hovewer when I try to invoke it line by line numpy do not give any problem but juliacall does not imports and gives

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'juliacall'
```

specs

Ubuntu

Python 3.10

Comment: have you installed juliacall or you just import the library if not you can installed by this command : pip3 install juliacall

Comment: can you try to import julia instead to import juliacall

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `juliacall` first, for example via `pip3 install juliacall`.

Comment: thanks @linuskmr but as I said when I execute whole file there are no problems ; pip3 install juliacall tell that requirement is already satisfied

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import juliacall as from juliacall import Main if you have already installed juliacall
see documentation [here](https://cjdoris.github.io/PythonCall.jl/dev/juliacall/)

Comment: thanks @abc bcd but as I said when I execute whole file there are no problems ; pip3 install juliacall tell that requirement is already satisfied ; and yes you are right about from juliacall import Main as jl but it dis not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out my mistake I used wrong interpreter
I needed to press ctrl+shift+p
python select interpreter

set it to the one on which pip operations were conducted

Comment: Use environments! https://realpython.com/effective-python-environment/